# Android - Google Map addMarker Title Not Showing on Map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dictionary

When i Use the `addMarker` Method for showing marker and title. it shows pin/marker but not title here i use below code

```
 mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(39.9612463, -75.620857))
        .title("Sample"))
        .showInfoWindow();

 mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(40.022478, -75.628103))
        .title("Sample1"))
        .showInfoWindow();

 mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(39.958016, -75.603278))
        .title("Sample2"))
        .showInfoWindow();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will show up after taping on the point to which you have add marker.
 add `.showInfoWindow()` at the end to display it always....

Comment: Thanks. working fine but i have to add 3 markers. it showing last title only sample2

Comment: it seems the `.showInfoWindow()` method has been removed

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 // latitude and longitude
double latitude = ;
double longitude = ;

// create marker
MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Hello Maps ");

// adding marker
googleMap.addMarker(marker);
```